# Loading neo4j query result into python's `igraph` graph

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, igraph

How would you load the results of a Cypher query into an `igraph` in python, keeping all the edge and vertex attributes?

Comment: This seems like the easiest way: http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#TupleList

Comment: Nicole: thank you. Can you write your suggestion as an answer so that I can "accept" it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is easy with py2neo and igraph's `Graph.TupleList` method.

You'll need both py2neo and igraph installed.

```
pip install py2neo
pip install python-igraph
```

Both of these packages rely on a `Graph` class so we should alias them as something else on import.

```
from py2neo import Graph as pGraph
from igraph import Graph as iGraph
```

First, connect to Neo4j with py2neo's `Graph` object.

```
neo4j = pGraph()
```

Then write a Cypher query to return an edgelist. Let's say we have the example movie dataset loaded into Neo4j and we want an edgelist of actors who have acted together.

```
query = """
MATCH (p1:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
RETURN p1.name, p2.name
"""

data = neo4j.cypher.execute(query)
print data[0]
```

This gives us an edgelist of actors who have acted together.

```
p1.name      | p2.name    
--------------+-------------
Hugo Weaving | Emil Eifrem
```

Conveniently, py2neo's `Graph.cypher.execute` returns something like a list of named tuples, so we can pass this directly to igraph's `Graph.TupleList` method to create an igraph object.

```
ig = iGraph.TupleList(data)
print ig
```

And now we have an igraph object.

```
<igraph.Graph at 0x1083a2908>
```

Who has the highest degree?

```
best = ig.vs.select(_degree = ig.maxdegree())["name"]
print best
```

Of course it's Tom Hanks.

```
[u'Tom Hanks']
```