# Build community in Neo4j via python

Tags: python, neo4j, igraph, py2neo

I have an neo4j graph. I wish to do community detection and other graph analysis such as betweeness and closeness through python programming.

I used py2neo to connect and query Neo4j. I dont know how to convert py2neo results so that python-igraph can take in and do analysis. My main aim is to do clustering of whole Neo4j graph

Answer (score 0):

So you want to export data from Neo4j into python-graph using py2neo?

You can pass [the result object](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#py2neo.cypher.RecordList) returned from py2neo's [Graph.Cypher.execute()](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html) method directly to python-igraph's Graph.TupleList constructor method to create an igraph Graph.

For example:

```
query = '''
MATCH (u:User)-[:BOUGHT]->(p:Product)
RETURN u.name AS user, p.name AS product
'''


results = graph.cypher.execute(query)
igraph = iGraph.TupleList(results)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31809054/2954199) for a more complete example.

Comment: 'to_subgraph' method was helpful for my scenario as I am reading whole graph for clustering.