# Dump a Neo4j graph in pickle format from AURADS via pGraph or iGraph

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook to run cypher queries via py2neo and pygds libraries. The instance is hosted on AURADS. I am not able to dump the graph from Neo4j to local computer in a  pickle file to explore later.

```
import neo4jupyter
import pickle
from py2neo import Graph as pGraph
from igraph import Graph as iGraph
from pygds import GDS
from graphdatascience import GraphDataScience

with open('graph.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(pGraph("<instance_credentials>", auth=("neo4j", "<instance_password>")), f)
print("Hello")
```

Here is the error I get with the above code:

[image]

I think I need to query the whole graph data first and then pickle it??
I found this answer, but it is not exactly what I am looking for:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129161/dump-a-graph-from-neo4j-with-pickle-in-python)

Comment: Yes, you need to query the graph data and then pickle it

Comment: @TomažBratanič thanks! Can you please let me know how I could do that? or at least I am looking for a query which will convert the graph data to a df in Notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the easiest thing to do is to separately export nodes and relationships.

You can export nodes using the following query:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

and relationships

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
RETURN n,r,m
```

Some variation of these two queries should be good. You can also take a look at APOC export functions: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/export/

Perhaps you could use apoc export to CSV and then construct a df from that:

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.all("graph.csv", {})
```